# Czech characters

Tags: python, kivy

I need to show Czech characters in PyCharm and Kivy apps. The encoding of the file is UTF-8, but Czech characters aren't showing correctly, for example:

[image]

but it's supposed to be Jméno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either Arial or DejaVuSans fonts.

[Kivy » Catering for Unicode languages](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#catering-for-unicode-languages)

> The font kivy uses does not contain all the characters required for
>   displaying all languages. When you use the built-in widgets, this
>   results in a block being drawn where you expect a character.
>
> If you want to display such characters, you can chose a font that
>   supports them and deploy it universally via kv:
>
> ```
> <Label>:
>     font_name: '/<path>/<to>/<font>'
> ```
>
> Note that this needs to be done before your widgets are loaded as kv
>   rules are only applied at load time.

## Example

### main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
GridLayout:
    cols: 2

    Label:
        font_name: "/home/iam/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/arial.ttf"
        text: 'Arial Fonts'

    Label:
        font_name: "/home/iam/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/arial.ttf"
        text: 'Jméno'


    Label:
        font_name: "/home/iam/share/fonts/dejavu_fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf"
        text: 'DejaVuSans Fonts'
    Label:
        font_name: "/home/iam/share/fonts/dejavu_fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf"
        text: 'Jméno'
"""))
```

## Output

[image: App Startup - Different Fonts for Czech]